# NullPointerException in setPreviewDisplay(holder)

Tags: java, android-camera

Pretty new on this android stuff and gets a NullPointException that I can't seem to figure out. I am trying to implement an onResume() method in my CameraActivity and have moved almost all of the orginal code in onCreate() to onResume() and then call onResume() in onCreate(). The activity worked fine when the code was in onCreate(), but when placed in onResume() the exception arsises. What is causing it?

```
package com.example.tensioncamapp_project;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private static final String TAG = "PreviewAactivity";
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;


public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    this.mHolder = getHolder();
    this.mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

/**Displays the picture on the camera */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        this.mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        this.mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
   this.mCamera.release();
    this.mCamera = null;
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    //add things here
}
}
```

and my CameraActivityClass

```
package com.example.tensioncamapp_project;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
private ImageButton captureButton;
private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private PictureCallback mPicture;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private static final int STD_DELAY = 400;
    private static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
protected static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";

/**Starts up the camera */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    onResume();

}   


/**Connects the capture button on the view to a listener
 *  and redirects the client to a preview of the captures image*/
private void addListenerOnButton() {
    this.captureButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_capture_symbol);
    this.captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View capturebutton) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            delay();
            Intent viewPic = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,      ViewPicActivity.class);
            startActivity(viewPic);
        }
    });
}


/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. Code collected from elsewhere */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        // attempt to get a Camera instance
        c = Camera.open(); 
        //getting current parameters
        Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters(); 
        //setting new parameters with flash
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        c.setParameters(params); 
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    // returns null if camera is unavailable
    return c; 
}

/**Generates a delay needed for application to save new pictures */
private void delay(){
    try {
        //Makes the program inactive for a specific amout of time
        Thread.sleep(STD_DELAY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
}

/**Method for releasing the camera immediately on pause event*/
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //Shuts down the preview shown on the screen
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    //Calls an internal help method to restore the camera
    releaseCamera();             
}


/**Help method to release the camera */
private void releaseCamera(){
    //Checks if there is a camera object active
    if (this.mCamera != null){
        //Releases the camera
        this.mCamera.release();
        //Restore the camera object to its initial state
        this.mCamera = null;
    }
}

/**Activates the camera and makes it appear on the screen */
    protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // deleting image from external storage
    FileHandler.deleteFromExternalStorage();
    // Create an instance of Camera.
    this.mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    this.mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this.mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(this.mPreview); 
    //add the capture button
    addListenerOnButton();
    // In order to receive data in JPEG format
    this.mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

        /**Creates a file when a image is taken, if the file doesn't already exists*/
        @Override 
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera mCamera) {

        File pictureFile = FileHandler.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
            return;
        }

        try {
            //Writes the image to the disc
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};
    super.onResume();
}



}
```

Log cat:

```
05-21 14:32:05.424: D/OpenGLRenderer(1030): Enabling debug mode 0
05-21 14:32:10.986: E/CameraActivity(1030): camera not availableFail to connect to   camera service
05-21 14:32:11.033: I/Choreographer(1030): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-21 14:32:11.203: W/EGL_emulation(1030): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-21 14:32:13.013: D/AndroidRuntime(1030): Shutting down VM
05-21 14:32:13.013: W/dalvikvm(1030): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.example.tensioncamapp_project.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:33)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:569)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:174)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1842)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-21 14:32:13.083: E/AndroidRuntime(1030):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's hard to see the line numbers here, can you supply the line (CameraPreview.java:33) throwing this exception?

Comment: /**Displays the picture on the camera */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        **this.mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);** //line that     results in exception
        this.mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to call the getCameraInstancemethod() in onResume() in an if-statement

```
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // deleting image from external storage
    FileHandler.deleteFromExternalStorage();
    // Create an instance of Camera.
    if (this.mCamera == null){
        this.mCamera = getCameraInstance();}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here

```
this.mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this.mCamera);
```

this.mCamera seems to be null, it's not be set a new instance of the class, this needs to be done in the getCameraInstance() method.

Answer (score 0):

`getCameraInstance()` returns null if an exception was thrown.
This cause the NPE as `this.mCamera` is `null`.

You should check if an exception was thrown in `getCameraInstance` and handle it correctly. The most basic thing is to log it and try to understand the reason.

Comment: You are right, the getCameraInstance() is throwing an exception saying "failed to connect to camera service". I am suspecting that I have't released the camera properly, but I can't figure out why..I released the camera in the onPause() method..

Comment: You can add the exact logcat of the exception you get to the question. It might help helping you...

Comment: posted the entire log above

Comment: No no no. I already told you why you get NPE. Now we need the logcat of the exception inside **getCameraInstance**.